# how to create shortcut for service application(its not stand alone application)?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix-extension

I want to create shortcut to service based application which should not be appear in shortcuts because it is my service and not a stand alone so that it will create shortcut test windows7 client logo certification test.

if there is any way please help me?

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify "service", because you cannot have a shortcut to a Windows service - a windows service is started by Windows in a special way, not by a shortcut.